# How do you change tambien to the negative?

Tags: vocabulario

How do you change "también" to the negative?
How do you change positive words into negative words?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a sentence where you would use "también" in the negative, to make it more clear what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

Tampoco is the antonym..

An example usage would be "Yo tampoco"... Me neither.

As far as changing positive words to negative, we're gonna need more example "positive" words.